# Firebase doesn't recognize that a DatabaseReference exists

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Noob here.

Trying to see if a DatabaseReference exists in my database. Here is how I do it:

```
String key = "ABCDE";
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("itemIds").child(key);
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) {
        if (!snap.exists())
            tellUserThatItDoesntExists();
        else
            tellUserThatItExists();
    }

    .....
}
```

But the code always results to the reference not existing even though a node `root/itemIds/ABCDE` (**which is BTW, I added through the Firebase console**) does exist in the database.

**All of the data is public**, so there is no reason for me to not be allowed to read data.

**Edit**: Here is a screenshot of the visual tree of the database. Everything here (except the `meh` node) was saved using Firebase console:
[image: Screenshot of the visual tree]

**Another edit**: Did some fiddling around and apparently, based on my observation, Firebase can't seem to read data that were added by the console. I have come up with this conclusion because I made the program I'm working on write something to the database and tried to check if that exists and it works fine.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please can you share a snap shot of your firebase data tree Or json of your firebase data ?

Comment: The reason I asked for the above is that I can't understand whether **root** is a node named root or you just referring the root reference as root. If it is a node then you need to add it before .child("itemIds")

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the root reference when I said root. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the reason for this error is obvious from your snapshot.

**Don't save data with - " " quotes!** Firebase reads the data added from console just fine. But if you are adding quotes then you have to refer as -  **.child(""itemIds"")**

Hope this helps. Remove the quotes and firebase will read it. Only the value for key can have quotes. Check the **meh** node how it is formatted. That is the correct way.

Comment: Geez. Didn't realized that. I'm dumb. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's alright. We all happen to make such errors. Please do consider upvoting the answer as well.